# askdirectory() changes focus to different window

Tags: python, focus, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to build two windows. One the main one, pressing a button leads to the creation of the second window.

This second window does not get focus immediately when it created. That I am able to fix by calling .focus_force(). However, when I call the askdirectory() function from tkFileDialog, the focus changes back to the first window.

How can I prevent that focus switch from happening, without simply calling focus_force() all over the place?

To replicate problem:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

class app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        Button(master, command = make_new).grid()
    def make_new(self):
        root = Tk()
        new = new_win(root)
        root.mainloop() #here the focus is on the first window
class new_win:
    def __init__(self, master):
        f = askdirectory() #even after placing focus on second window,
                           #focus goes back to first window here
```

I am using Python 2.7.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the little-documented wm_attributes method might help:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

root = Tk()

top = Toplevel()
top.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
top.withdraw()
top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', top.withdraw)

def do_dialog():
    oldFoc = top.focus_get()
    print tkFileDialog.askdirectory()    
    if oldFoc: oldFoc.focus_set()

b0 = Button(top, text='choose dir', command=do_dialog)
b0.pack(padx=100, pady=100)

def popup():
    top.deiconify()
    b0.focus_set()

b1 = Button(root, text='popup', command=popup)
b1.pack(padx=100, pady=100)
root.mainloop()
```